# Show SQL Query based on selected option

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I have a form where you can select a vehicle:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="vehicle" class="col-3 col-form-label">Fahrzeug</label> 
<div class="col-auto">
        <select id="vehicle" name="vehicle" class="custom-select" onchange="selectedVehicle(this.value)">
                <option disabled selected style="display: none">Fahrzeug auswählen...</option>
                <?php  
                    require_once('php/DBconnect.php');
                    mysqli_select_db($link, 'db') or die('Cannot select database. ' . mysqli_error());
                    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT vehicle_id, license, model FROM vehicle");
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        echo "<option value='". $row['vehicle_id']. "'>  ". $row['license'] ." | ". $row['model'] . "</option>";
                    }
                ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the same form, I have a button, which opens a modal, to display already existing damages to the vehicle.

Now I want to insert per PHP data from SQL queries to the modal based on the selected option. Like the head in the modal should display the license plate based on the selected vehicle_id.

In my JS I have the following code:

```js
function selectedVehicle(vehicleID){
    createCookie("vehicle", vehicleID, "10");

    document.getElementById("modalListDamageTitle").innerHTML = 
        "<?php 
            require_once('php/DBconnect.php');
            mysqli_select_db($link, 'db') or die('Cannot select database. ' . mysqli_error());
            $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT license FROM vehicle WHERE vehicle_id = $vehicleID");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
            echo $row['license'];
        ?>";        
}
```

First I tried to pass it directly, then I tried it with cookies, but nothing works. How can I solve this problem? How can I pass a PHP snippet a javascript variable in a javascript?

Comment: You're either going have to reload the page or perform an AJAX call to get the db data. You can't inject it into innerHTML after the page has already loaded without using AJAX. More to the point, the DOM cannot run your PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ajax to get the data from the database. 
For example on the button which calls the modal add onclick="get_data(pass_selected_id)" 
This method I am using in one of my applications. Hope this helps.

```
  <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicExampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-large modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Raporti i mungesa per kete produkt</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">





                    <script>
                        function get_data(id){

                            $.ajax({
                                url:"actions/your-script.php",
                                method:"post",
                                data:{id:id},
                                success:function (response) {
                                    $(".modal-title").html(response);
                                }

                            });


                        }
                    </script>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- end of modal-->
```